# Why is my code showing me the error message of "object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"?

Tags: python-3.x, string-length

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Y7A.png)

[Content of the file I want to read(d0.txt)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh8lU.png)

I am currently studying python and I have a homework that looks like below. I don't know where I made a mistake and it is showing that "object of type 'NoneType' has no len()". Can anyone help me out why it's showing this error message?

```
import sys
import os.path
# Add your function definitions here
def getData():
  fLocation="C://TEMP//"
  print("Assumed file location is at: ", fLocation)
  fName = input("\nPlease enter a file name with its extension (ex. XXX.txt): ")

  fin = open(fLocation + fName, 'r')

  aStr = fin.read()

  aList = aStr.split()

  aLen=len(aList)



def main():

  integersInAstr = getData()
  if (len(integersInAstr) == 0):
    print('*' * 30 + "\nReceived an empty string and no number to process, so the",
                                                            "program terminates.\n")
    sys.exit()
  else:
    print('*' * 30 + "\nReceived data items:\n" + integersInAstr)
```

BTW this is what I got when I execute the program:

Assumed file location is at: /Users/Ivan/Desktop/

```
Please enter a file name with its extension (ex. XXX.txt): d0.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Ivan/Desktop/search.py", line 89, in
main( )
File "/Users/Ivan/Desktop/search.py", line 42, in main
if (len(integersInAstr) == 0):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: What is `getData()` supposed to return? Right now you're missing a `return` statement so it doesn't actually return anything.

Comment: Please edit your question to include text as text, not images

Comment: @Mihai. But it does. Every function in Python with no explicit return value returns None.

Comment: Yes, apologies for being careless with the language I was using. None is in fact **something**.

Comment: @Mihai. And mine for being overly pedantic. I understood your meaning just fine. Just emphasizing that your observation completely answers the question.